# Javascript reduce are getting ugly undefined

Tags: javascript, json, nested, grouping, reduce

I worked some array of object for advanced my skills. When i paste first code and run it, i will get second console log. I would like to group in by year and in volume. First of, Can you tell me, why i getting many undefined in reduce array. Second of,  how can i reduce with this json like third code? Do you know where i can practice about these?

Thank you so much already now.

```
// first code:
const data = 
  [ { year: 2015, name: 'fizz', volume: 1, issue: '1'   } 
  , { year: 2016, name: 'fizz', volume: 2, issue: '2'   } 
  , { year: 2017, name: 'fizz', volume: 3, issue: '3'   } 
  , { year: 2017, name: 'fizz', volume: 3, issue: '3-1' } 
  , { year: 2018, name: 'fizz', volume: 4, issue: '4'   } 
  , { year: 2018, name: 'fizz', volume: 5, issue: '5'   } 
  ]


const reduced = data.reduce((r, o) => {
  r[o.year] = [...r[o.year] || [], o];
  return r
}, []);


console.log(reduced);
```

```
//console.log:
[undefined, undefined, undefined, unde..., [{
  issue: 1,
  name: "fizz",
  volume: 1,
  year: 2015
}], [{
  issue: 2,
  name: "fizz",
  volume: 2,
  year: 2016
}], [{
  issue: 3,
  name: "fizz",
  volume: 3,
  year: 2017
}], [{
  issue: 4,
  name: "fizz",
  volume: 4,
  year: 2018
}, {
  issue: 5,
  name: "fizz",
  volume: 5,
  year: 2018
}]]
```

I would like to this:

```
// third code
const Expected = 
  [ { 2015: 
      [ { 1: [ { year: 2015, name: 'fizz', volume: 1, issue: '1' } ] } 
      ] 
    } 
  , { 2016: 
      [ { 2: [ { year: 2016, name: 'fizz', volume: 2, issue: '2' } ] } 
      ] 
    } 
  , { 2017: 
      [ { 3: 
          [ { year: 2017, name: 'fizz', volume: 3, issue: '3'   } 
          , { year: 2017, name: 'fizz', volume: 3, issue: '3-1' } 
      ] } ] 
    } 
  , { 2018: 
      [ { 4: 
          [ { year: 2018, name: 'fizz', volume: 4, issue: '4' } 
          ] 
        } 
      , { 5: 
          [ { year: 2018, name: 'fizz', volume: 5, issue: '5' } 
  ] } ] } ]
```

Comment: why is there a `issue: 3-1`  ?

Comment: Ohh sorry, that is a sample

Comment: So, where is the logic between object in `// first code` and object in `// third code` ?

Comment: Oh sorry you right, the data has been like this:

  { year: 2015, name: 'fizz', volume: 1, issue: 1 },
  { year: 2016, name: 'fizz', volume: 2, issue: 2 },
  { year: 2017, name: 'fizz', volume: 3, issue: 3 },
  { year: 2017, name: 'fizz', volume: 3, issue: 3-1 },
  { year: 2018, name: 'fizz', volume: 4, issue: 4 },
  { year: 2018, name: 'fizz', volume: 5, issue: 5 },

Comment: I have added my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The accumulator is an *array*, not an object, so assigning to an `o.year` property of the array puts a property with a large index on it - 2015, to be precise. The previous 2014 elements will be `undefined`.

Group into an object instead of an array, and you'll also have to account for the odd nested object/array structure inside each year object:

```js
// first code:
const data = [
  { year: 2015, name: 'fizz', volume: 1, issue: 1 },
  { year: 2016, name: 'fizz', volume: 2, issue: 2 },
  { year: 2017, name: 'fizz', volume: 3, issue: 3 },
  { year: 2018, name: 'fizz', volume: 4, issue: 4 },
  { year: 2018, name: 'fizz', volume: 5, issue: 5 },
];


const reduced = data.reduce((r, o) => {
  if (!r[o.year]) {
    r[o.year] = {[o.year]: []};
  }
  r[o.year][o.year].push({ [o.volume]: [o] });
  return r
}, {});


console.log(Object.values(reduced));
```

Answer (score 0):

My way..

```js
const data = 
  [ { year: 2015, name: 'fizz', volume: 1, issue: '1'   } 
  , { year: 2016, name: 'fizz', volume: 2, issue: '2'   } 
  , { year: 2017, name: 'fizz', volume: 3, issue: '3'   } 
  , { year: 2017, name: 'fizz', volume: 3, issue: '3-1' } 
  , { year: 2018, name: 'fizz', volume: 4, issue: '4'   } 
  , { year: 2018, name: 'fizz', volume: 5, issue: '5'   } 
  ] 

const reduced = data.reduce((r, o) =>
  {
  let aYear = r.find(x=>x[o.year])
  if (!aYear) 
    {
    aYear = { [o.year]: [] }
    r.push( aYear)
    }
  let aVolume = aYear[o.year].find(x=>x[o.volume])
  if (!aVolume) 
    {
    aVolume = { [o.volume]: [] }
    aYear[o.year].push( aVolume )
    }
  aVolume[o.volume].push( {...o})
  return r
  }, [])

console.log ( reduced  )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100% !important;top: 0;}
```